# How do I create a android service that runs continuosly?

Tags: android

I would like to notify my users of new content available in the latest version of my android game without using an external service like Push Notifications.

What I would like to do as a first step to achieve this is to just create a standard notification on application update.

This brings me to my question: is it possible to start a service the first time a user launches the game and then just keep it running indefinitely? I want to even keep it running after an update completes. Since it is possible that the code for the service may have changed between versions, would I need to stop the old version of the service manually and start the new version? Is it possible to even do something like this where the event that drives initiation of the service is the completion of an app upate?

My plan is to have this service check some persisted data about the last time the user was notified about new content and based on this I will be able to determine if a notification should be created for them after they update.

It's important that they are not required to go back into the game after update in order for the notification to be created. This is the problem that I am having now. Auto-updates occur and they don't know and hence also don't know that there are new stages, etc, available so they never go back into the game if they were already done with the previously available content.

It seems that games like Family Guy have got this approach working, but I am not sure if they implemented it in this way. Even after I update it, I will still get notifications even if I have not actually executed the app since update.

Comment: "is it possible to start a service the first time a user launches the game and then just keep it running indefinitely?" -- **only have a service in memory when it is actively delivering value to the user**. Sitting around, waiting for new content that may never exist, is not delivering value to the user. Use `AlarmManager` and check nightly or something.

Answer (score 0):

Services are mostly killed when other process needs the resources. Therefore use

```
startForground(...)
```

for running Services indefintly on background.

See here: [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground(int](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground%28int), android.app.Notification)

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use the `AlarmManager` in your service that notifies you at certain time. Start the service,  do the task and set again an alarm to notify you. In this way, you'll be able to run your service infinitely at periodic time.

Answer (score 0):

> I started redacting this answer on GameDev Stack Exchange before you
>   deleted the question. Unlike the guy who told you to delete, i thought it was an interesting question even for game dev stack exchange.

What you describe is a bad practice on android. I don't believe any game do that. What's more, android require "service" app to run as [ForegroundService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) (This force you to display you app icon in the notification bar, so that users are always aware of running services) It can also be randomly be killed when the system lacks memory. However it can be implemented nicely using [Alarms](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html) and [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html).

### Services and Notifications :

You can however schedule intents when the app is running, with [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html), this is the good practice. Let's take a simple exemple : Candy Crush.

In Candy Crush, when you lose your last life, every 30 minutes you regain one, and have a limit of 5 lives. You want to notify the user when all his lives are back. How to do that ?

**Exemple 1 :**

- When the user lose his last life or quit the game, schedule an intent with AlarmManager in (5-number_of_life)*30 minutes that will fire a local notification.

**Exemple 2 :**

- Schedule an intent with AlarmManager every 30 minutes to check the number of lives, and fire a notification when the user have 5 lives again.

Using a Boot receiver may also allow you to schedule things as soon as the device boot.

However, users **expects** to be able to disable this kind of features.

### Updates :

If you want your app to notify users when an update is available, you'll need to somehow check on the internet with a request on your server. You may schedule an intent again with alarm manager to check regularly if the update is available. If the user is ingame, you can also check it more regularly.

A lot of "online" games do that, and simply force the user to download the new update from the Play Store, before they can play again.